# How to prepare for segue and send data from 1 label to another?

Tags: swift, uilabel, segue

I am developing a QR code reader application. Here is the code:

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var qrCodeframeView: UIView?

@IBOutlet weak var CancelButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    CancelButton.hidden = true
    Label.hidden = true


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func ScanMe(sender: AnyObject) {

    CancelButton.hidden = false
    Label.hidden = false


    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error: NSError?
    let input: AnyObject!

    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput (device: captureDevice)
    } catch let error1 as NSError{

        error = error1
        input = nil

    }

    if (error != nil){
    print ("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)

    let captureMetadatOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadatOutput)

    captureMetadatOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    captureMetadatOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

    captureSession?.startRunning()
    view.bringSubviewToFront(Label)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(CancelButton)

    qrCodeframeView = UIView()
    qrCodeframeView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    qrCodeframeView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
    view.addSubview(qrCodeframeView!)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeframeView!)


}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {

        qrCodeframeView?.frame = CGRectZero
        Label.text = "No QR code detected"
        return
    }
    let metadateObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if metadateObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {

        let BarcodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadateObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        qrCodeframeView?.frame = BarcodeObject.bounds

        if metadateObj.stringValue != nil {

            Label.text = metadateObj.stringValue

            captureSession?.stopRunning()



 }
  }
 }


@IBAction func Cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    CancelButton.hidden = true
    Label.hidden = true


    captureSession?.stopRunning()
    qrCodeframeView?.removeFromSuperview()
    videoPreviewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()


}

@IBAction func Open(sender: AnyObject) {

}
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
        var PC : SecondSecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondSecondViewController
   PC.label1 = Label.text!
  }


  }
```

When I write the function `prepareForSegue`, I am trying to send the data from `Label.text` (the result from the scan) to `label1` in my next `UIViewController`. Unfortunately, `Label.text` is colored in red (cannot assign value of type `String` to type `UILabel`).

Do you have any idea how can I manage that? (I want only to send the scanned information to the other `UIViewController`)

Comment: Might seem like a minor thing, but you really should not capitalize your variables. It makes your code harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in this:

```
PC.label1.text = Label.text!
```

You are trying to assign a String to a variable of type `UILabel` instead of its text value.

Comment: Works also perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your destination VC - SecondViewController add this variable:

```
var labelText : String = ""
```

in the same class add this line into viewDidLoad() method:

```
label1.text = labelText
```

Then you need to access that string variable and put the value in it.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
        var PC : SecondSecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondSecondViewController
        PC.labelText = Label.text!
}
```

Comment: I have forgotten that. Thank you very much for the reminder!! It works perfect

Answer (score 1):

`PC.label1`  unable to load data set `PC.label1.text`

try this way

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
            var PC : SecondSecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondSecondViewController
       PC.label1.text = Label.text!
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

add PC.label1.text = Label.text!